# PdfSharp System.NotImplementedException: Cannot create value for key: /Info

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, pdfsharp, migradoc, pdfsharpcore

I have written an app in C# with Visual Studio using PdfSharp & MigraDoc. This works fine.
When I build the app as standalone exe then the app will crash when I will calculate the text with with the method MeasureString.
The Exception which I will become is System.NotImplementedException: Cannot create value for key: /Info
I will only get this error when the app is a standalone exe. When I compile it as not a standalone exe then it works.

I have googled it but only find this link here on GitHub: https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/issues/120
They are using Unity and not Visual Studio. And I don't know where to place this files which they have added.
Does somebody know how to solve my problem?
If nothing works, then I have to use the complete folder with the dll's inside instead of a standalone exe.

The traceback:

```
System.NotImplementedException: Cannot create value for key: /Info
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDictionary.DictionaryElements.GetValue(String, VCF)
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfTrailer.get_Info()
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.get_Info()
   at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument..ctor()
   at PDFVerificationProtocol.PDFCreator.CalculateRequiredColumnWidth(String) in Z:\PDF-Prüfprotokoll_Test\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFCreator.cs:line 381
   at PDFVerificationProtocol.PDFCreator.AddPSetTable(Section) in Z:\PDF-Prüfprotokoll_Test\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFCreator.cs:line 229
   at PDFVerificationProtocol.PDFCreator.Run() in Z:\PDF-Prüfprotokoll_Test\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFCreator.cs:line 54
   at PDFVerificationProtocol.Program.RunProgram() in Z:\PDF-Prüfprotokoll_Test\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFVerificationProtocol\Program.cs:line 34
   at PDFVerificationProtocol.Program.Main(String[]) in Z:\PDF-Prüfprotokoll_Test\PDFVerificationProtocol\PDFVerificationProtocol\Program.cs:line 11
```

In this method occurs the problem:

```
private double CalculateRequiredColumnWidth(string text)
        {
            // Use the global style font settings
            XFont font = new XFont(globalStyle.Font.Name, globalStyle.Font.Size);

            // Dummy
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            document.AddPage();
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(document.Pages[0]);

            // Measure the width of the text using XGraphics
            XSize textSize = gfx.MeasureString(text, font);

            // Calculate the required width including padding
            double requiredWidth = textSize.Width + (2 * cellPadding);

            return requiredWidth;
        }
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work but add the file to you project then right click on it, choose properties, and on build have it copy the file if newer. That should place it in the build output and maybe it will get picked up.

Comment: I think I have the solution. The problem is that I use the trim option from Visual Studio. This will reduce the file size of the exe. When I don't use it, the app work as expected. Now I have to figure out how to exclude MigraDoc/PdfSharp from trimming. Edit: Got it. I had to set the ```<TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>``` option inside the PropertyGroup in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that, as the author of the question already mentioned, `<TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>` in the `.csproj` file under `<PropertyGroup>` indeed is sufficient to resolve this issue. In my specific scenario, the relevant portion of the `.csproj` file appears as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    ...
    <TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
...

</Project>
```

Alternatively, you can uncheck the "Trim unsued code" option in the Publish dialog. However, in this case, the .exe file will be relatively large.

[image]